# Android twopane layout on fragment creates null object

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment class, from this call has twopane layout invoices_view.xml

```
<fragment class="lk.ezbiz.mobile.ui.InvoiceListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/contact_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/contact_list_percent"/>

<fragment class="lk.ezbiz.mobile.ui.InvoiceDetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/contact_detail"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/contact_detail_percent"/>
```

and my class is,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = null;

    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invoices_view, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

        isTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);

        if (isTwoPaneLayout) {

            mInvoiceDetailFragment = (InvoiceDetailFragment)
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contact_detail);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: " + ex.toString());
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

to show the selected item in left pane i need to use this InvoiceDetailFragment object (mInvoiceDetailFragment), but its null, if the main class is an activity it works fine, but i need the main class to be a fragment. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nest Fragments inside Fragments call getChildFragmentManager() instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()